# Replacing non-breaking space with space when pasting into a cell

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to find the best way to convert a non-breaking space to a regular space when pasting data into a cell. I receive an excel file from a vendor and copy their data into a spreadsheet which I then use to generate another report. Their spreadsheet includes non-breaking spaces which became an issue. I used search and replace on my current data to replace char(160) characters with " ". Now I need to find a way to format the cell so that it automatically converts this way upon pasting into that column.

Additional information about the data:
It is housed in column B, cells B2 and down.
The data is a combination of numbers and letters.
The data is always formulated as: five characters, two spaces, 16 characters, five spaces, 10 characters
Example: X0000  XXX0000000000000  0000000000

I tried various substitute formula variations which I can make work, but I want to avoid using these formulas because I do not want another column of the same data and cannot perform the function on the cell itself due to circular reference errors.

Comment: This is easily accomplished with VBA.

Comment: Thank you, I just added the tag. I am not very familiar with VBA programming. Can you provide any feedback or point me in the right direction to achieve the result I need?

Answer (score 2):

With [vba](/questions/tagged/vba), using the [`Worksheet.Change`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheet.change) event.

In the sheet code module (right click the tab and select "View Code"), add:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Not Intersect(Me.Range("B:B", Target)) Is Nothing Then
        On Error GoTo SafeExit
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        
        Me.Range("B:B").Replace What:=Chr(160), Replacement:=" "
    End If
    
SafeExit:
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```